# sql find rows partially matching a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find rows in table having rows which contains a string

For example, I m having rows in a column names 'atest' in a table named 'testing' -

```
test
a
cool
another
```

now I want to select the rows having a word from the string 'this is a test' using a sql

```
select * from testing where instr(atext, 'this is a test') >0;
```

but this is not selecting any row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the arguments to [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr).

```
WHERE INSTR('this is a test', atext)
```

Comment: instr in programming languages is the reversed way of mysql, funny why is this so?

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya I've never seen `INSTR` in another programming language.  The only analog I can think of is PHP `strpos`, which has the same argument order as MySQL.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya JavaScript has no `instr`.  And what would you define as an old language?  PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript all appeared in 1995.

Comment: yeah js has kind of instr, indexOf :) anyways you defined old lang :)

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya but `indexOf` does not have the `needle, haystack` argument order.  If anything it's closer to `haystack, needle`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25973/discussion-between-pradyut-bhattacharya-and-explosion-pills)

Comment: mysql also has `locate`, with the first two parameters in the other order (plus an optional third parameter which is not needed here)

Comment: C's [strstr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/) has needle, haystack

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'reversed' like:

```
select * from testing where 'this is a test' LIKE CONCAT('%',atext,'%');
```

It can be slow on tables having a lot of records.
This returns the rows, where the value of the atext column can be found in the given string.
(for example matches when atext = 'is a t' because it can be found in the given string)

Or you can write a regex.

```
select * from testing where atext REGEXP '^(this|is|a|test)$';
```

This matching all rows what contains exactly the specified words.
In your scripting or programming language, you should only replace spaces with | and add ^ to the begining of the string and $ to the ending of the string, and  REGEXP, not equation.
("this is a test"  -> ^this|is|a|test$ )

If you have a lot of records in the table, this queries can be slow. Because the sql engine does not use indexes in regexp queries.

So if you have a lot of rows on your table and does not have more than 4 000 000 words i recommend to make an indexing table. Example:

```
originalTable:
tid | atext (text)         
1   | this is        
2   | a word         
3   | a this
4   | this word      
5   | a is
....



indexTable:
wid | word (varchar)
1   | this
2   | is
3   | a
4   | word


switchTable:
tid | wid
1   | 1
1   | 2 
2   | 3
2   | 4
3   | 1
3   | 3
...
```

You should set indexes, tid, wid and word fields.

Than the query is:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM originalTable as o
JOIN switchTable as s ON o.tid = s.tid
JOIN indexTable as i on i.wid=s.wid
WHERE i.word = 'this' or i.word='is' or i.word='a' or i.word='test'
```

This query can be mutch faster if your originalTable have 'a lot' records, because here the sql engine can make indexed searches. But there is a bit more work when insert a row in the original table you must make insertions in the other two tables.

The result between the runtime of the 3 queries depends on your database table size. And that you want to optimize for insertions or selections. ( the rate between insert/update and select queryes )

Answer (score 0):

with full text index -

```
select * from anti_spam where match (atext) against ("this is a test" in boolean mode);
```